# Show PCs behind router as single PC to hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I travel a lot.  When I travel, I carry my own router with me so I can share files between devices without having to worry about other people getting into them.

My router supports Wi-fi to Wi-fi bridging.  So I can for example connect my router to the Wi-fi of my hotel, then my computers can share the internet.

However the hotel internet still sees each computer as a device on the network, requiring me to login 3x (once from each device).  Also I have a device (smart TV without a browser) I use that does not have a browser so I cannot log into the internet on that one at all.

I am sure in this circumstance I am actually connected to my Wifi not the hotels.  And I would have thought once I logged onto one device the hotel Wifi would have registered my Router MAC and then all my devices should work.  But this has not been the case.

Any idea how to accomplish this?  I am moderately familiar with DD-WRT if that would help.

My Devices -------> My Hotspot ----> Hotel Wifi ----> Internet

Comment: You seem to be in Access Point mode, rather than Bridge mode. Your local WiFi subnet should be on a different subnet from the hotel's, and you should be using the router to log on.

Comment: So are you saying I need to find a router with an embedded browser?

Comment: Most modern routers have an HTML interface, and this allows you to set the parameters needed for the appropriate mode. For bridge mode, you should be able to set the SSID and password, and this should then get access for its subnet. You should experiment with connecting to your home router until you are sure of the configuration before going away and hoping to set it up there.